# C# WPF binding to method with ObjectDataProvider

Tags: c#, wpf, objectdataprovider

I have a strange behaviour using `ObjectDataProvider`. I need to bind a `TextBlock` with `ToString` method but, when I enter in method my properties are wrong.

This is my simple `ObjectDataProvider`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ToString" MethodName="ToString" ObjectType="{x:Type entities:Season}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And this is my `ListView`:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Name="lvSeasons" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ToString}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Click="btDeleteSeason_Click">
                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Text="&#xf1f8;" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My method simply concat two properties:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return StartYear + "/" + EndYear;
}
```

In debug I can see that start and end year are always 0. If I bind my `TextBlock` using `{Binding StartYear}` it's correct and value is 2019.

Where can the problem be?

Comment: Well, why do you need to get a string using this way? You can use it in binding directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an ObjectDataProvider. Just write

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" ... />
```

WPF will call the ToString method by default.

You do not even need to override ToString when you use a MultiBinding with an appropriate StringFormat:

```
<TextBlock ...>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}/{1}">
            <Binding Path="StartYear "/>
            <Binding Path="EndYear "/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine, but where is the problem with my code? Why start and end year are 0?

Comment: The ObjectDataProvider doesn't know the item instance. It creates its own Season instance because you have set the ObjectType property.

Comment: Ok. And how can I use my binding instances?

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6585303/1136211) perhaps.

Comment: Also with `DataTemplate.Resources` it doesn't work. Same problem.

Comment: I have always Start and End year set to 0. I want to undestand how `ObjectDataProvider` works. If I try to call a method in my window it doesn't fire, if I call method in my entity then the entity is an "empty" instance.